# How to move logo and search into header in RWD theme

Tags: header

I need change the position of logo, search bar, account link and cart link **to the header**.

I Need to change the position of the following

1. LOGO
2. SEARCH BAR
3. ACCOUNT AND CART LINK

Refer attached image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to your template dir and copy/past the following dirs+file:

```
page/html/header.phtml
```

On line 45 you will see the anchor tag that contains the logo. 
You can move this element to whatever you want in this template file.